# MSI installer VS 2008

Tags: windows-installer

I want to read the users directory which user chooses to install my MSI, so that i can write the path to the registry which is required for my application to run. I want to know how to do this, if using any scripts then kindly let me know the script as i am totally new here for this installer.

Comment: If you are referring to a per-user location for saving application data, I recommend the AppDataFolder property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367565(VS.85).aspx . You can set the registry value to "[AppDataFolder]".

Comment: thanks i asked this question later, actually i needed both targetdir and appdata folder. thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry that is not resolved, i added Users Application Data Folder in File System, added a file to it so that the MSI copies to users application data folder of local machine, but its not copying to C:\Users\<user>\AppData folder, kindly let me know how to copy to users AppData folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put [TARGETDIR] ( or the name of any other directory property inside of [] ) in the registry value and the value of TARGETDIR will be written to the registry.

Comment: in the same way i want to know how to get the user folder in local machine, i want to copy a file to C:\Users\<userid>\AppData\LocalLow\.